# Mount device as RW for root and RO for everyone else

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, fstab, readonly

I have a device I want to mount for root with full permissions and for everyone else as readonly. The man page tells me this is possible.

So:

- `sudo mkdir /mnt/foo`
- `sudo mkdir /mnt/fooReadOnly`
- `sudo chmod 700 /mnt/foo` (rw for root only)
- `sudo chmod 555 /mnt/fooReadOnly` (ro / browse for everyone)
- ensure device `/dev/sdaX` is mounted as `/mnt/foo`

Then I did what the man page suggested:

- `sudo mount --bind /mnt/foo /mnt/fooReadOnly`
- `sudo mount -o remount,bind,ro /mnt/foo /mnt/fooReadOnly`

Now to test:

- `ls /mnt/foo` --> `Permission denied` ...**CORRECT**
- `sudo ls /mnt/foo` works ..**CORRECT**
- `ls /mnt/fooReadOnly` --> `Permission denied` ...**INCORRECT?**

I cannot change anything on that bind mount, it tells me `Read-only file system`.

How do I fix this?

Also, how do I add this to `/etc/fstab` so that it will automatically remount on boot?

Comment: Once you mount on top of a directory, the permissions of that directory are ignored - we can only see the permissions of the directory which is mounted on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a device I want to mount for root with full permissions and for everyone else as readonly.

- `sudo mkdir /root/mnt/foo`
- `sudo mkdir /mnt/fooReadOnly`
- `mount -oro /dev/sdaX /mnt/foo`

  - This ensures device /dev/sdaX is mounted *readonly* on /mnt/foo. I set this up first, because it is not possible to create a read-only bind mount in a single step. I don't want to let users access a read-write bind mount, even for an instant.
- `ls -ld /root` - double-check this shows the mode `dr-xr-x---` and owner `root root`.
- `sudo mount --bind /mnt/fooReadOnly /root/mnt/foo`
- `sudo mount -oremount,rw /root/mnt/foo`

Try the above commands. After each mount command, you can run `grep foo /proc/self/mountinfo`, which shows the per-filesystem and per-mountpoint flags in separate columns.

To understand this, know that `mount -oremount,rw` (or `mount -oremount,ro`) changes both the per-filesystem flag and the per-mountpoint flag at the same time. But it does not affect the per-mountpoint flag of the *other* mount point(s).

---

It is not possible to try the above commands inside a user namespace (`unshare -rm`), even if you switch to mounting a tmpfs instead of sdaX. It fails with "permission denied" at `mount -oremount,rw`.  Instead you would have to use the following sequence:

- `mount tmp -ttmpfs /root/mnt/foo`
- `mount --bind /root/mnt/foo /root/mnt/fooReadOnly`
- `mount -oremount,bind,ro /root/mnt/fooReadOnly`
- `mount --bind /root/mnt/fooReadOnly /mnt/fooReadOnly`

---

> Also, how do I add this to /etc/fstab so that it will automatically remount on boot?

I would recommend not adapting the first sequence to fstab, because it is too much of a hack.  You can adapt the second ordering instead.

```
/dev/sdaX /root/mnt/foo ...
/root/mnt/foo /root/mnt/fooReadOnly none bind,ro
/root/fooReadOnly /mnt/fooReadOnly none bind
```

Comment: Lots to digest... new to this! I still have trouble getting the RO mount to work. Once I do `mount -oro /dev/sdaX /mnt/foo` I try `ls /mnt/foo` but get "Permission denied" which shouldn't happen, as it's intended to be RO by anyone?

Comment: @lonix I suspect you unintentionally set strict permissions on the root directory of the /dev/sdaX filesystem. Check `ls -ld /mnt/foo` (after mounting it).